# How can I get the last name in a path next to the right of a \ character using RE on Python?

Tags: python, path, python-re

I have been trying to make a good regular expression that catches the last name (of a file or folder) for a given path, meaning that for instance, the following path:

> C:\Users\ResetStoreX\Pictures

Can be reduced to:

> Pictures

What I have achieved so far is the following RE: `(?:[^\\]\\)[^\\]*$`

Which reduces the previous path to:

> X\Pictures

Any ideas?

Comment: You dont. Use `os.path.basename`. Use string.split and split on the os specific path seperator and take the last part. Etc ... so many ways to do it.

Comment: OP needed a regex answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it.  I removed the \ inside of the parentheses, if you want all backslashes to be captured.

```
(?:[^\\])[^\\]*$
```